# Where can I ask about non-platform specific questions about mobile devices?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've asked the following question on *[Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour)*, where it was closed as off-topic.

Network Engineering said [questions about hosts are off-topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68570/do-mobile-devices-vary-transmission-power-based-on-signal-strength), and Android Enthusiasts said they disallow questions which are [Android-independent](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226114/do-mobile-devices-vary-transmission-power-based-on-signal-strength). I expect *[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour)* will say the same thing.

> **Do mobile devices vary transmission power based on signal strength?**
>
> Do mobile devices typically vary transmission power according to the
> reception strength?
>
> e.g. Will my phone use more battery if I'm far from my router?

Comment: You could cheat and ask that question specific for your Samsung 5G ... then rinse repeat on Ask Different for your iPhone 11. An alternative, but that might need some consulting on their site specific meta, is asking on Electrical Engineering where you then have to ask if there are chips/ components that are able to do what you "want' (to know). It helps if you know type/brand/manufacturer of the component that does the transmission stuff.

Comment: There's also a dedicated site for Windows Phone.

Comment: @rene err... cheating the question by adding a specific device won't help on Android.SE if the underlying topic itself is unrelated to Android...

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you can get regarding questions about (hardware) platform unspecific mobile devices is **[SE Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)**. They support a [mobile](/questions/tagged/mobile) tag.

The other option (especially if software might be involved) is as @rene mentioned in [their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349718/where-to-ask-about-non-platform-specific-questions-about-mobile-devices#comment1170438_349718):
Ask your question independently at all mobile platform specific SE sites and refer to a recent specific mobile phone. ATM these are

- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (Apple HW & SW)
- [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Take note that Android.SE still considers questions as off-topic (Android-independent) if the questions don't have anything specifically with Android, e.g. general policy on WhatsApp.